# Copying specific subfolders with directory strucutre through Windows CMD?

Tags: cmd, copy

I have following folder structure.

```
                 media
                   |
  -----------------------------------
    1day          2day          3day
     |             |             |
 ---------     ---------     ---------
 |   |   |     |   |   |     |   |   |            
hin eng fra   hin ger spa   hin eng vie
```

I want to copy all the subdirectories (`1day, 2day, 3day`) to a new folder. But I only want to copy `hin` and `eng` folders (and files inside it) in the new place.

Not sure how could it be done via Windows CMD.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please regard that StackOverflow is a programmers' Q&A site but not a free code/script writing service! Please read the [tour] and learn [ask] here! Hint: take a look at the [`xcopy` command](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) (particularly its `/EXCLUDE` option) or the [`robocopy` command](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)...

Answer (score 1):

Robocopy, xCopy commands doesn't itself have an include feature, they all have exclude feature. Because, by default they include everything within the folder. That is the reason why the same question was asked several times in past couple of years here and there on the web without a concrete solution.

Following command helps to break above rule by using "FOR" command and it works like a charm.

`FOR /D /R %G IN (hin.*) DO ROBOCOPY "%G" "DRIVE:Folder\%~pG%~nxG" /E /S /NP`

From the source folder, it will copy any directory that has the name "hin" and creates the same folder structure on destinated drive/folder.

There is `GUI` software which might help non-coders.

`RichCopy via Microsoft` (free, does have both include and exclude feature in advanced option, however include feature didn't work, for windows only)
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx

`Easy RoboCopy` (free, does not have include feature but has exclude feature, for windows only)
http://www.tribblesoft.com/home-page/easy-robocopy/

Both `RichCopy & Easy RoboCopy` is GUI of Robocopy command.

`FastCopy` (free, does have both include and exclude feature, for windows only)
https://fastcopy.jp/en/

`RapidCopy` MAC version of FastCopy (paid, for mac only)

`GSCOPY PRO / GSRICHCOPY360` (paid, have both include & exclude feature, for windows only)

`TeraCopy` (paid, have both include & exclude feature, for windows only)

I have TRIED & TESTED all except RapidCopy which is in MAC. Also tested trial version of GSCOPY & TeraCopy. However, **FastCopy wins it all.**

I hope this helps.

_/_